# Error converting NSString to C-String

Tags: c++, objective-c, unicode, nsstring, unicode-string

I am trying to convert `NSString` to C-String` using the following call:

```
NSString* path = ...
const char* str = [path cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

The `path` contains a file path. But, I am getting str as just "/". When I use this call instead:

```
const char* str = [path UTF8String];
```

The returned `str` is fine i.e. I get the required path as a c-string. But, I need to make sure that the conversion works in all cases regardless of the the type encoding used in the path i.e. I want to take care of unicode characters. And for that I need to use the initial call.

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the encoding you chose.  UTF-16 will return the characters in 16-bit and you are expecting 8-bit characters (i.e. UTF-8).

So if the path starts with `/`, that will be returned as `0x2F00` (assuming little-endian encoding) and the `00` sequence will look *end of string*.

Comment: That is correct. But, how do I make sure that the code handles all the unicode characters?

Comment: @Sankalp Not sure you really can.  Each type of unicode encoding (UTF-8, -16, -32) as well as each type of endian (both big and little) requires special handling.  I think you should always expect and handle UTF-8 and nothing else.  If you have strings encoded externally (in files, for example) then these should be converted to UTF-8 prior to processing by your program (i.e. while they're loading).

Comment: So, I guess, I just have to pray that the path is being UTF-8 encoded while loading!

Comment: @Sankalp No need to pray.  The methods you use have explicit behaviour so you know the encoding of the string you will receive.

Comment: So, do you mean that there is a way to recognize the encoding of NSString I am getting? If yes, then it would be of great help.

Comment: @Sankalp I think you are getting confused. `NSString` uses UTF-16 (or maybe UCS-2) internally to store the string but will give it to you in whatever encoding you like (within reason).  You have already demonstrated this with the code you have posted.  So you just need to ask it for the string data in whatever encoding you want to handle it in, which should be UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that NSString stores in UTF-16 internally. So, to get the UTF-16 encoded string, should I be using wide characters (`wchar*`)? Or, further, if I simply convert it to UTF-8 encoding, will I be loosing some data or will there be mismatch in actual path name and the name which I'll be using to open the file?

Comment: @Sankalp I would use `unichar` for a UTF-16 character, however you won't lose any data by getting it back in UTF-8.  All system calls support UTF-8 (as far as I know) so just use that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using UTF8 encoding this '\' you get will be the first of the NSString...in c each char takes 1 byte (8bits) but UTF16 makes characters 2 bytes long.. and so the error occurs